# After drop event i view duplicate event Mysql database

Tags: database, events, fullcalendar

After i have dropped the event in the fullcalendar I see my dropped event and the event rendered from mysql database.

This is my code:

```
success: function (json) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                    }
```

How i can delete or not view the dropped events ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved in this mode:

```
success: function (json) {
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents') //Hide all events
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', start);
                    }
```